Django " [ was not closed " error in url routing
I'm new to python. Trying to understand and following the tutorials. One of the many tutorials that I follow, in django for url routing we are creating url.py and put our routing logic inside that file as below:
urlpatterns = [
    path=("",views.index),
    path=("/index",views.index)    
]

In every tutorial that syntax is working. But in my example it throws an error as below:

I did not understand why it is showing me error and not for others.
Also I have tried so assign path method into a variable and after that It worked.

Am I missing syntax rule or someting?

The = is  not allowed there. In the recent version Pylance gives this rather misleading error message.

And that second one doesn't really work either. indexUrl = path=("", views.index) creates two variables "indexUrl" and "path" with the tuple ("", views.index).

@KlausD. thanks I noticed it now

you dont need = here
urlpatterns = [
    path=("",views.index),
    path=("/index",views.index)    
]

it should be
urlpatterns = [
    path("",views.index),
    path("/index",views.index)    
]

